# Can .nomedia exclude file type?

Tags: media-player, gallery, file-management

In my Music folder, I have many subfolders for albums and they each have their album art in .jpg or .png format. I want the media scanner to not pick up these files however if I do that, then the entire Music folder would have nothing in it.

Is there any way to only exclude certain file formats? My gallery is cluttered with album art at the moment.

I also don't want to delete any of the album art.

EDIT: Requesting tag "media-scanner" to be created.

Answer (score 4):

.nomedia is on or off, no way to exclude just certain file types. You might want to try including the album art in the music files (it'll still show up in the music player) and then copying them over, rather than adding the art to the folder on your phone.