# How do I exclude album art from the gallery?

Tags: gallery, album-art

The answer to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12835/can-nomedia-exclude-file-type) is not valid, because embedding the album art inside the media files does not always work, as I outlined in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63650/how-do-i-change-incorrect-album-art-on-the-default-music-player-of-the-samsung-g).

So basically, I want the hundreds of album art images to stop showing up in my gallery. I can't use `.nomedia` because that would invalidate any music in the same directory. Are there any other options?

Comment: I've had no issues using .nomedia. The music files still show up in Poweramp.

Comment: @geffchang Maybe Poweramp doesn't use the systems media database (which the media scanner feeds). Players who do will no longer find the music files, as `.nomedia` would keep the media scanner from adding them to the library.

Comment: NobleUplift: I don't know of a way working with the default Gallery app. But there are gallery apps where you can exclude folders. If you're open to an alternative Gallery app as solution, you can check with [my list of gallery apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=54) (might be faster than searching Play directly).

Comment: See my answer to a similar question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/157544/how-do-i-get-gallery-and-photos-to-ignore-the-images-in-a-specified-directory/250110#250110)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rename the album cover to "folder.jpg", and it will be skipped. You can save the rest of the album art in a nested folder with ".nomedia" inside it.

Comment: ARG! I've been using AlbumArt.jpg this whole time! And to put salt in the wound, Windows generated a few Folder.jpg files and I renamed them to AlbumArt.jpg before transferring :\

Comment: My album art is all saved as `folder.jpg`.... What gives?

Answer (score 0):

I have two Gists that can be used to either system hide every "Folder.jpg" or "AlbumArt.jpg" so that they are not uploaded to my phone:

https://gist.github.com/NobleUplift/d0524f901994ecb5e46d

Or remove that file in every subdirectory:

https://gist.github.com/NobleUplift/8c9e3b524284ac766b63

I actually use Windows Media Player for all of my syncing now instead of copying my entire music library, and I've begun to embed 500x500 album art images into all of my MP3s. I would suggest this for anyone else who is uploading album art to his or her phone.

Answer (score 0):

rename the file to folder.jpg and/or albumart.jpg (not sure about this one. please check) and it should be skipped.

other option is to use .nomedia file. If you use a music player that as an option to ignore .nomedia, you can have a .nomedia file in your music folder and the album art wont appear in gallery.

third option is to use embedded artwork.

Comment: First option is already posted as answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/85941/119358) and Second option is gathere from the comment [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/69168/119358) Also could you explain how third option works? What is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: @Manubhargav Embedded artwork means embedding the image into the mp3 file, most practically using the `ID3 Tag` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just use poweramp as suggested, best music player on Android in my opinion anyway, and have your music in a folder with a .nomedia folder in it easy peasy.

Comment: Please link the app from play store

Answer (score 0):

I also have a gist located here: https://gist.github.com/essboyer/3f84afc9595b068869fb0baf1e2a51b5

Note that this code will DELETE any image that is not `folder.jpg`. It will attempt to rename a few common misnamed folder filenames, and you can always easily add your own!