# How do I get Gallery and Photos to ignore the images in a specified directory?

Tags: gallery

When I open Gallery or Google Photos, there are dozens or hundreds of albums and photos that have been automatically pulled from my Music directory, where there are lots of JPEGs that are cover art for MP3 files.

They make it so that it is very hard to find particular photos I've taken with my camera, and in any case it is useless to have them displayed there as I never want to browse music cover art in my Gallery.

I can't find any option to exclude folders, though. **How do I make it so the image files in my Music directory are not included in Gallery or Google Photos?**

Comment: @beeshyams, thank you for responding. If I put `.nomedia` to my music folder, won't that also stop my MP3 files from being seen by music apps?

Comment: @beeshyams, the solution for playing music from a folder with a `.nomedia` file in it is to use a different music player than I am now. I don't want to have to take on specific music player apps in order to handle a problem with image galleries.

Comment: @beeshyams, Thanks for your continued interest. I'm using N7 Player. And it's not the best player, but, if I have to choose between the hassle of unwanted images in my gallery and the hassle of using a new music player that I didn't select for it's features but for one obscure file handling issue, I'll go with the devil I know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to this old question:

NB :

- this applies to

  - Android 13
  - the [Samsung gallery application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.gallery3d)
- various hacks suggested by other answers did not work for me :

  - **.nomedia** files
  - renaming all album art files to **Cover.jpg** / **AlbumArt.jpg** / whatever

How to proceed :

1. start the **Gallery** application
2. click the bottom-right **hamburger icon (≡) | Settings**
3. disable the **Select albums to display** option. This actually controls which option will appear hereafter :

   - when **enabled** : you'll get **Select albums to display**
   - when **disabled** : you'll get **Select albums to hide**
4. leave the **Settings** page
5. click the **Albums** bottom tab
6. open the top-right menu **3 vertical dots (⋮) | Hide albums**
7. select the albums you want to hide

After that, you'll have to clear the Gallery's cache :

1. return to your Home screen / App screen (the screen having the **Gallery** icon)
2. long press the **Gallery** icon until a context menu appears
3. in this context menu, click the top-right **circled "i" ⓘ**
4. on this new **Application information** page, click on **Storage**
5. click **Purge cache**
6. enjoy

source : https://doc.callmematthi.eu/Android.html#hideAlbumArtFromGalleryApp